# Is there a specific order of parameters used in spark-submit while submitting a job?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to submit a spark job using spark-submit as below:

```
> SPARK_MAJOR_VERSION=2  spark-submit --conf spark.ui.port=4090
> --driver-class-path /home/devusr/jars/greenplum-spark_2.11-1.3.0.jar  --jars /home/devusr/jars/greenplum-spark_2.11-1.3.0.jar --executor-cores 3 --executor-memory 13G --class com.partition.source.YearPartition splinter_2.11-0.1.jar --master=yarn
> --keytab /home/devusr/devusr.keytab --principal devusr@DEV.COM --files /usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/conf/hive-site.xml,testconnection.properties
> --name Splinter --conf spark.executor.extraClassPath=/home/devusr/jars/greenplum-spark_2.11-1.3.0.jar
> --conf spark.executor.instances=10 --conf spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=false  --conf
> spark.files.maxPartitionBytes=256M
```

But the job doesn't run and instead just prints:

```
SPARK_MAJOR_VERSION is set to 2, using Spark2
```

Could anyone let me know if there is any specific order for the parameters used in spark-submit ?

Comment: Is `/home/devusr/jars/greenplum-spark_2.11-1.3.0.jar` the jar which contains your **main class** ? If so, you need to pass it as the last argument of the spark-submit option. If not, that is what you're missing - `spark-submit` expects its last argument to be the _program_ to run, it may be a **Scala/Java JAR**, a **Python Script or Egg file** or a **Zip with R files**.

Comment: --driver-class-path /home/devusr/jars/greenplum-spark_2.11-1.3.0.jar is the driver class I trying to mention. The driver class I am applied in the code is: com.pivotal.jdbc.GreenplumDriver in "class.forName("com.pivotal.jdbc.GreenplumDriver")

Answer (score 1):

The format to use `spark-submit` in `cluster` mode on `yarn` is 
`$ ./bin/spark-submit --class path.to.your.Class --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster [options] <app jar> [app options]` as documented in https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/running-on-yarn.html

If `splinter_2.11-0.1.jar` is the jar that contains your class `com.partition.source.YearPartition`, Can you try using this:

```
spark-submit \
        --class com.partition.source.YearPartition                                              \
        --master=yarn                                                                           \
        --conf spark.ui.port=4090                                                               \
        --driver-class-path /home/devusr/jars/greenplum-spark_2.11-1.3.0.jar                    \
        --jars /home/devusr/jars/greenplum-spark_2.11-1.3.0.jar                                 \
        --executor-cores 3                                                                      \
        --executor-memory 13G                                                                   \
        --keytab /home/devusr/devusr.keytab                                                     \
        --principal devusr@DEV.COM                                                              \
        --files /usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/conf/hive-site.xml,testconnection.properties     \
        --name Splinter                                                                         \
        --conf spark.executor.extraClassPath=/home/devusr/jars/greenplum-spark_2.11-1.3.0.jar   \
        --conf spark.executor.instances=10                                                      \
        --conf spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=false                                            \
        --conf spark.files.maxPartitionBytes=256M                                               \
        splinter_2.11-0.1.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no proper order while writing spark submit command. Just few things are to be taken care.
The command should start with spark-submit if you are in the same directory where spark is installed else you need to provide the full path before spark-submit command. The order of spark options and configs can change. But at last, you should provide the executable jar location and after that the arguments used in the application which you want to pass. For example:

> **/local/spark/lib/spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster ..-spark configs-.. /tmp/app.jar arg1 arg2**